# Incomplete type when assigning array of structs to another struct member

Tags: c, struct

I've been at this for a while and I can't seem to figure out what's happening. I give empty definitions for the structs in a header file so they are opaque.

```
typedef struct block_store block_store_t;
typedef struct block block_t;
```

In a different file I actually define them.

```
struct block_t{
    void* data;
};    

struct block_store_t{
     block_t* b;
 };

void create_struct(){
    block_store_t* bs = malloc(sizeof(block_store_t*));
    block_t* array = malloc(sizeof(block_t*) * 256);

    bs->b = array;  //error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
 }
```

Comment: Are the `typedef`s also known (aka included) in your "different" file? It seems the compiler doesn't know about the `typedef`s

Comment: I include the correct .h file in my .c file if that's what you're asking. Is there something else I need to do in the .h file?

Comment: `block_store` and `block` are incomplete... Perhaps you meant `typedef struct block_store_t block_store_t;` and etc...

Comment: You have typos either in the `typedef` or in the `struct`, see DeiDei's comment.

Comment: You have `block_t` as a `typedef` for the type `struct block`, and similarly for `struct block_store`; that is, you need to define the type `struct block`, not `struct block_t`,  so change: `struct block_t { void* data; };` --> `struct block { void* data; };` and `struct block_store_t { block_t* b; };` --> `struct block_store { block_t* b; };`

Comment: Also note that it is best (and idiomatic C) to call `malloc()` like: `block_t *array = malloc(sizeof *array * 256);`. That is, use an identifier instead of an explicit type as the operand for `sizeof`. This is less error-prone and easier to maintain. And don't forget to check for allocation failure....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typedef` the `struct` before using it in the another structure like

```
typedef struct block{
        void* data;
}block_t;    

typedef struct block_store{
     block_t* b; /* it works bcz you typedefed before only */
}block_store_t;
```

Also `sizeof(block_store_t*)` should be `sizeof(block_store_t)` as first one only allocate equal to `struct pointer` size but you may want to allocate equal to whole struct size.

```
block_store_t* bs = malloc(sizeof(block_store_t));/* allocate memory equal to sizeof structure, not just 4 bytes */
//block_t* array = malloc(sizeof(block_t) * 256);
block_t* array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * 256);/*preferable to use bcz it work for any data type */
```

Comment: No, it should **struct block_t** because that's the user-defined type name.

Comment: Both `malloc(sizeof(struct block_t))` and `malloc(sizeof(block_t)` are fine. 2nd one is correct if you did `typedef`.

Comment: bedbad I thought that looked funny as well but I was given the header file and told to implement them myself. @achal Thanks for the help and good catch on my bad malloc that went uncaught by the compiler

Comment: He didn't do the typedef and they can't both be fine. typedef is just an alias type. I suggest you try to compile both of them in one place and see what's happens.

Comment: @OmegaCollision malloc is dynamic and therefore will never be caught by the compiler. Things that can be checked at compilation called static, like typedefs, for example.

Comment: @bedbad I typdef  `struct block` as `block_t` and then suggested `malloc(sizeof(block_t))` in my  suggested answer.

Comment: @achal There's no argument here if you read me again. The mistake you made is "they are both fine". That is incorrect. Typedef are simply static aliases and you can't type struct struct something - it will be a syntax error.

Comment: @OmegaCollision I suggest trying to understand things systematically first, otherwise, you'll spend a massive amount of time on such mundane errors, that will never "be caught by the compiler." Don't do it the hard way)

Comment: @bedbad If you don't mind could you explain why my initial implementation was bad? Since I already did it once in my .h file why do I need a second typedef?

Comment: That's because compiler passes the code top - down.(which includes just make like 1 single text compile, if that's the compilation unit)  So what you need to do is to include struct definitions in the header file itself, before typedefs. Or just don't use typedefs.

Comment: yup I agreed @bedbad I misinterpreted while commenting. It should be `malloc(sizeof(struct block))` not `malloc(sizeof(struct block_t))`

Comment: @OmegaCollision  The best(and pretty much only) way to learn C is to read K&R C book and a Unix OS book, because that's where malloc and dynamic things come from. I can tell you from experience, your learning curve will be great and you'll save yourself a lot of time.  You can finish it in a week and totally master C.

Comment: @bedbad -- K&R is a great book, but very out of date. Not the best book to learn from at first (in my opinion, but many agree with me on this). And there is no way to master C in one week.

Comment: By the quality, I consider it's the best programming language book ever written. C(up to 99) became the most influential language because of that book. I think this a kind of advice Kernigan, Stroustrup, Knuth etc will give, so I'm not sure that age is a factor here.

Answer (score 2):

The posted code shows `block_t` as a `typedef` for the type `struct block`, and similarly `block_store_t` is a `typedef` for `struct block_store`. OP needs to define the types `struct block` and `struct block_store`, not `struct block_t` and `struct block_store_t`. Change the definitions to:

```
struct block {
    void *data;
};

struct block_store {
    block_t *b;
};
```

Note also that there are errors in the calls to `malloc()` in the posted code. The first call needs to allocate storage for a `block_store_t` structure, so this should be something like:

```
block_store_t* bs = malloc(sizeof (block_store_t));
```

The second call needs to allocate space for 256 `block_t` structures:

```
block_t* array = malloc(sizeof (block_t) * 256);
```

There is an idiomatic way of writing this code in C that is less error-prone, avoiding the particular mistake made in the posted code. This idiom also results in code that is easier to maintain when types change during the lifetime of the code:

```
block_store_t *bs = malloc(sizeof *bs);
block_t *array = malloc(sizeof *array * 256);
```

Here, identifiers are used instead of explicit types as operands for the `sizeof` operator.

Note also that `malloc()` may return a null pointer if an allocation fails. This condition should be checked for and failures handled by the code.

Since the question suggests that there should be multiple files, here is an example solution with a header file and two source files:

A header file containing `typedef`s, `struct` definitions and function prototypes:

```
/* bstore.h */

#ifndef BSTORE_H
#define BSTORE_H

typedef struct block_store block_store_t;
typedef struct block block_t;

struct block {
    void *data;
};

struct block_store {
    block_t *b;
};

block_store_t * create_store(void);

#endif
```

A source file containing function definitions. Note that OP code contained `create_struct()` which returned `void`; it seems that such a function should return a pointer to `block_store_t`, but maybe OP has different goals. Here, the function `create_store()` does return a pointer to `block_store_t`. Also note that allocation errors are handled here by exiting with an error message; OP may elect to handle errors more gracefully:

```
/* bstore.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bstore.h"

block_store_t * create_store(void)
{
    block_store_t *bs = malloc(sizeof *bs);
    if (bs == NULL) {
        perror("Failure in block store allocation");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    block_t *array = malloc(sizeof *array * 256);
    if (array == NULL) {
        perror("Failure in array allocation");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    bs->b = array;

    return bs;
}
```

A source file containing `main()`:

```
/* main.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bstore.h"

int main(void)
{
    block_store_t *my_store = create_store();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
        (my_store->b[i]).data = "testing";
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
        puts((char *) (my_store->b[i]).data);
    }

    free(my_store->b);
    free(my_store);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Detailed explanation. Good one.

Answer (score 0):

You're making basic C mistakes.
When you do memory allocation make sure you are allocation the right sizes.
Size of a pointer to a struct will be the same as a size of any other pointer most probably and there will be an error when you'll try to address that region as a whole struct.

```
struct block_store* bs = malloc(sizeof(struct block_store));
struct block* array = malloc(sizeof(struct block) * 256);
```

Regarding typedefs - they are just aliases not to right long "struct name"
Make sure they are visible.